# Streaming HTTP audio feed on Alexa

Tags: audio-streaming, alexa-skills-kit

Accordingly to https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference:

> The audio file must be hosted at an Internet-accessible HTTPS
>   endpoint. HTTPS is required, and the domain hosting the files must
>   present a valid, trusted SSL certificate.

I want to build a skill to stream a feed from http (NOT https) endpoint. How do I do this?

There are other skills (like TuneIn radio) which seem to stream http feeds. Unless they proxy them, which would be a significant overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out Alexa can play HTTP audio feeds. I just had too put those as references inside of .m3u file, which is served by HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem that you had 2 years back. Can you please help me with how you manged to solve this issue.